# I lost administrator permissions in the C directory and now I can only create new folders in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, administrator

I recently installed Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) on my Desktop and after I realized I lost control over C I deinstalled it and restarted my computer but I still had my problem.

I still have admin rights over the E directory and I am using Windows 10.

net localgroup Administrators shows up my user as administrator.

I can only create new folders as seen here

[image]

I can't save to Desktop anymore

[image: image2]

Comment: Can you provide the ACL for the folder in question?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, sounds like either (*1*) you have a virus (*...or malware/ransonware/etc...*) or (*2*) a permissions script ran and locked up the ACLs.  Likely on a LOT of folders other than the ones you know about.

I have seen Oracle software come with scripts that modify permissions, so if you installed Oracle to anything other than the default location, you likely have this issue.

The quickest way to fix it, is to restore windows from a previous restore point. ([link](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-system-restore-windows-10#recover_restore_point_windows10))
Otherwise, you'll need to get "creative".

(**1**) Backup your data to an external drive, scan it for viruses on a computer not
connected to the Internet or any network connection.

(**2**) (assuming Retail Windows 10, otherwise contact your IT immediately) On another "clean" computer, create a Windows Install USB by following these instruction. ([link](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-usb-bootable-media-uefi-support#create_windows10_uefi_mct))

(**3**) Wipe your computer and re-install Windows 10 using the USB you created in step (**2**).

(**4**) Install a good antivirus if Windows Defender isn't your favorite. I like ESET NOD32 Antivirus myself.

(**5**) After patching the OS and updating the OS and AV, copy your files back to you computer and enable System Restore. ([link](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-system-restore-windows-10))

(**6**) Install all of your other software.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try creating a brand new account on the computer.  See if that ones allows you to manipulate folders.  If it does, then simply after copying (*not moving...*) your files to the new account, delete the old non-functional account.